# need help where to put my datediff query in this code

Tags: php, mysql

Were can i insert my datediff query in this code

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents where docnum  "My Search Bar"='$_SESSION[test2]' and doctitle LIKE '%$search%' order by docprim desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<tr class ='hovered'>";

   echo "<td width = '100px' class='text-left'>";  
   echo $row['docnum'];
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td width = '100px' class='text-left'>";
   echo $row['datein']." to ".$row['dateout'];
   echo "</td>";

}
```

this is a sample of my code. i want to add duration from datein and dateout field from my table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your SQL Query String.

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d');
$enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 days"));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents where docnum ='".$_SESSION['test2']."' and doctitle LIKE '%$search%' and DATEDIFF('".$startdate."', '".$enddate."') > 0 order by docprim desc");
```

Also your SQL Query string has issues. Let me know if you need help with that as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir its getting me warning

Comment: Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '8.0/no DST' instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\deped\documents_viewrecord2.php on line 77

Comment: Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '8.0/no DST' instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\deped\documents_viewrecord2.php on line 78

Comment: Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '8.0/no DST' instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\deped\documents_viewrecord2.php on line 78

Comment: You'll have to set the default date time zone in your php ini configuration. Either that or you can use the `date_default_timezone_set` function in your index php file. That should solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Insert TIMESTAMPDIFF before '*' in sql-query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, d.datein, d.dateout) AS timediff, m.* FROM documents m;
```

and use as:

```
echo $row['datein']." to ".$row['dateout'] . " (" . $row['timediff'] . ")" ;
```

$row['timediff']  will show seconds.

Comment: yes sir. but when i insert this code it gets errors. can you help me where exactly i would insert this code. sample $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents where docnum ='".$_SESSION['test2']."' and doctitle LIKE '%$search%' and SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, d.datein, d.dateout) AS timediff, m.* FROM documents m; > 0 

order by docprim desc");

Comment: shows this Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\deped\documents_viewrecord2.php on line 80

Comment: Correct SQL-query: $result = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, m.datein, m.dateout) AS timediff, m.* FROM documents m WHERE m.docnum ='".$_SESSION['test2']."' and m.doctitle LIKE '%$search%' order by m.docprim desc");